# Why show popup function of combobox is not working in qt?

Tags: qt, combobox

I am new to qt and just experimenting with some functions of comboBox.
I have written the following code

```
ui->comboBox->addItem("mark");
ui->comboBox->count();
ui->showPopup();
```

in main window() of project
this code has added mark to the comboBox if i write the following code

```
ui->comboBox->addItem("mark");
```

but count() and showPopup() are not working and following error is coming.
class Ui::MainWindow has no member named show Popup.

Comment: Use: _ui->comboBox->showPopup();_ instead of: _ui->showPopup();_

Answer (score 1):

as you can see in the qt doc here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#showPopup

showPopup is a method defined in the combobox and not in the mainWindows class

so you need to do

```
ui->comboBox->showPopup();
```

instead of:

```
ui->showPopup();
```

on the other hand, the function count() defined here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#count-prop
is actually returning the number of items in the combobox

so when you do

```
ui->comboBox->count();
```

and ignore the returned value, well.. it just get lost in the app...

try comething like

```
qDebug() << "Elements in CB: " << ui->comboBox->count();
```

so you can printed in the terminal as a debug message...